# How to host multiple applications in the same Azure Web App Service?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I would to host two ASP.NET Core Applications, a Web API and a Blazor Server App, but I searched in the internet and the answers that I founded only target to a different path inside of one application, that's not my case. I would to use they like a sub-address of the same Azure Web App for example: **www.example.com** and **www.example.com/api** where each one will be a different .NET Core application. So I suspect that I'll need to create two Azure App Services and try to communicate they both, but maybe the structured that I wonder won't work in this way, it's that right? How I can do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have the same setup as you; an ASP.NET Core web API, and a Blazor Server Side app.

As you want to use the same domain for both services, you would have to use Azure API Management or some other proxy if you were to route requests to two different Azure App Services.

An easier option is to deploy both services to the same App Service, but as [different virtual applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common#configure-path-mappings). You publish your Blazor app as normal, but for the Web API you would publish to a new virtual application `/api`.

To enable this virtual application, navigate to *Configuration* and then *Path mappings* in your App Service. Here you already have the default virtual application `/` pointing to `site\wwwroot`. You then add another virtual application named `/api` pointing to `site\wwwroot\api`:

[image: Azure App Service Configuration]

When adding the virtual application, remember to remove checkbox for *Directory* (making it a virtual application instead), and optionally enable Preload:

[image: Add Virtual application to Azure App Service]

If you publish your app using Azure DevOps Pipeline, it has an option to [specify virtual application](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeploymentV4/README.md) if another than default should be used.

You can now navigate to your two different URLs and hit each service. Note that when developing your Web API, you should not add `api` to your controllers routes, as this virtual application does that for you.

Comment: So if you had 2 api's how do you specify slot settings or can you not use them if you do that?

Comment: If I understand the question right, both APIs will run inside the same App Service and therefore also in the same slot. So if switching deployment slot both APIs will be switched.

Comment: FYI: `Virtual Applications and Directories` option is not available with App Services on Linux. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/664517/azure-web-app-missing-virtual-directory-option.html