# Azure AppService - Runtime Stacks

Tags: php, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service

For research purposes, I wanted to test how Azure AppService runtime stacks work and I am currently hosting two applications in one Azure AppService (Wordpress and ASP.NET) in separate paths as you can see here:

[image: Path mappings]

Everything works fine as I am able to access both applications through browser. What makes me wonder is: how is it possible for both applications to work no matter which runtime stack I choose?

I have tried these two runtimes and both applications work exactly the same:

- **.NET**

  [image: .NET Runtime]
- **PHP**

  [image: PHP Runtime]

Seems like all runtime environments are already set up even if you do not choose them. **So, what is the point of choosing between them? Is there any difference?**

**EDIT**: I have checked in the app console and I can confirm that all supported runtime environments are installed (for any runtime stack selected in the app):
[image: Installed runtimes]

Comment: Hi pbdiazam; this is an excellent question, but can I make one suggestion? Can you copy and paste the information from the screenshots into the question in text format? It helps make a question more searchable, indexable, etc.

Comment: I am able to post pictures now. I edited the post and I think its easier to read :D

Comment: Could you please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443304/how-to-host-multiple-applications-in-the-same-azure-web-app-service?rq=1 ..May it helps