# Multiple apps on azure domain

Tags: .net, azure, hosting

Not sure if anybody can help me here.
Ok, so we have a domain example finance.co.za in azure app. This is the domain that holds both front end and backend apis.  This is done in .net Mvc framework.

Now with our rewrite, we have our new react website that will be published into the above domain (finance.co.za).
And we have created api.finance.co.za which will hold the apis that we did as a part of rewrite.

Ok now- the caveat here is the consumption of our old apis. There are external parties that do not want to change their api end points to call our new api end points.

However, that domain (finance.co.za) will be holding the new react code and the old Mvc would have disappeared..

Is there a way to just retain the old api coding under the same domain, so the external parties don't have to change anything.

Am confused and cannot get this right.

I have tried url rewrite on the old api web.config to route to the new api if we get requests, but it's clearly not working.

Any help on this regard will be much appreciated here.

Tx
Shank
0027 73 77 65695

Answer (score 0):

> Multiple apps on azure domain

- You can achieve this by using Application Gateway
- As per this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview),

On the same application gateway deployment, you can host many subdomains of the same parent domain.

Using public-facing listeners, you can configure multiple web applications on the same port of application gateways.

- We can also create Azure web apps and deploy them to virtual directory with the same name in Azure Portal
- We need to add the New Virtual application or directory under Path Mappings in Configuration section of your deployed Web App

[image]

Please make sure you are deploying you Web Apps in ***Azure Windows Web App***.
Option to add Virtual applications and directories is not available in ***Azure Linux App Services***

[image]

***References taken from***

[How to Deploy Multiple Apps on Azure WebApps](https://dotnetthoughts.net/deploying-multiple-application-in-webapp/)

[How to host multiple applications in the same Azure Web App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443304/how-to-host-multiple-applications-in-the-same-azure-web-app-service)