# How to host 2 server in one Azure App Service?

Tags: reactjs, django, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I'm having a web app which is based on ReactJS (Frontend) + Django (Backend), I've integrated ReactJS with Django and make it as single server based application.
I have 1 more server which is based on Express JS separately. I'm trying to host my web application in Azure app service and publisher is Docker Container. So, I am hosting React + Django based web app in 1 app services it is successfully getting hosted along with the SSL certificates.

Now, I am trying to host Express JS in same web app in which I hosted React + Django based web app since Django + React is running on port 80 . I am not able to host Express JS in same app service and if I am trying to host Express JS on separate app service, it is getting hosted but now domain is changed or there need to be some subdomain which I don't want.

PROBLEM:
I want to host both Django+React server and Express JS server in same app service in which my main web-app is hosted.

Comment: AFAIK, You cannot host 2 Web apps in the same app service, They can share the same app service plan, But you need to create separate JS Web app like here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-nodejs?tabs=windows&pivots=development-environment-vscode for your express js app and if you keep the same domain, you can make use of APIM and the answer from this SO thread- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443304/how-to-host-multiple-applications-in-the-same-azure-web-app-service by Frode evensen

Comment: An alternative is to add your express js source code folder in wwwroot and then use path mapping to that folder to deploy both the apps in same web app, For steps refer here- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/host-multiple-application-in-a-single-azure-app-service

Comment: One more option is to use Multi-container apps where you can deploy both your applications in different containers, For tutorial, Refer here-https://github.com/Azure-Samples/multicontainerwordpress

Comment: @SiddheshDesai Thanks for your help, but the link you have [mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59443304/how-to-host-multiple-applications-in-the-same-azure-web-app-service) those're not valid. The app service in which i am (using publisher as Docker container). **Virtual** **Applications** **and** **Directories** option is not available.

Comment: I think the mapping with / is not supported in Azure web app with docker container refer the Limitations here- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-connect-to-azure-storage?tabs=portal&pivots=container-windows#limitations Did you try checking a multi-container approach? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/multicontainerwordpress

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web app with docker container does not have Virtual Application and Directory option, But they do have Storage account option to mount your files in the Web app.  And it will only work for the Mount path supported below:-

[image]

An alternative is to deploy your Express.js app in another App service that is deployed in another Region and another Resource group, As you are trying to Deploy Express.Js app in the same region as your existing Web app that hosts React+Django app, you are receiving an error related to the Domain.

Refer this [**brtach-MSFT answer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/202552/running-same-custom-domain-in-different-azure-app)

> As custom domain works on DNS, Ideally one record points to one app service, Thus its not possible to have another web app pointing to the same record, Unless you create a new App service in new region and resource group and point a new record to your Custom Domain service provider's site. this will create both your apps in different region and in different underlying web space or web server thus the custom domain can be added. You can validate the IP address of both the Apps and make sure the Inbound IP of both app services are different.

Added this custom domain in another app where the web app with docker container is in different region and different resource group.

[image]

One more alternative is to Deploy a Multi-container app with both the apps reactjs+Django and expressjs by referring this [MS Document sample which deploys a Wordpress app in multi container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app):-

[image]

[image]