# How to point Azure virtual path to another app service?

Tags: wordpress, azure, dns

I need to move a wp blog to another azure app service.

The existing path of the blog is mydomain.com/blog

I created a new app service which handles the new wp blog. How do I point the domain to the new app service (different IP) using the same path mydomain.com/blog?

Please note that mydomain.com on the current app service still being use for the main website. Thank you.

So basically I wanted to point mydomain.com/blog to new app service but mydomain.com remains to be pointed to current app service.

The virtual path to physical setup on current app service is /blog -> site\blog

I wanted the /blog to redirect to new app service with same /blog.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to host the same domain in another Web app but the another web app should be created in a different Region and different Resource group. If you want to use the same virtual path in the path mapping and same domain, The another Web app in Azure should be in a different Web space and Web host. Refer the Note in my [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76454202/how-to-host-2-server-in-one-azure-app-service/76464514#) here and [**Answer**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/202552/running-same-custom-domain-in-different-azure-app) by brtrach-MSFT

If you use add the custom domain to 2 apps in same resource group and same region you will receive an error like below:-

[image]

***I added the domain to the Wordpress app named silicon-webapp1 deployed in Australia East region*** like below:-

[image]

Now, ***I created another Wordpress app in UK South named vallerywebapp2 and added the same domain.*** The ***domain was registered successfully*** like below:-

[image]

When *I visit my custom domain of vallerywebapp2 above, The Web app page loads successfully*:-

[image]

In addition you can make use of [**Azure Application Gateway**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/application-gateway/configure-web-app.md) to route traffic to between both of your web apps.